# Timing belt changed, won't start

Tags: engine, honda, accord, timing-belt, timing

I just did the timing belt change in a Honda 2007 V6 Accord. I thought I aligned the belt, but I guess I didn't. Now it won't cranks but won't start.

How do I fix the timing issue?

mark on Crank is facing 9:00,
front cam has #1 at TDC
rear cam mark is at 9:00.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Is it kicking over at all (attempting to fire) or does it just crank and crank and you hear nothing besides the starter running?

Comment: It turns out I really screwed up the timing. I watched many youtube video s and read many instructions, but still messed it up, So I had a mechanic come over and we got it corrected. But now it runs incredibly rough and stalls. he thinks I bent the valves when I tried to start it  with the timing off. Any guesses or suggestions?

Comment: What he says sounds reasonable. You'd need to do compression and/or leak down tests to show if you bent valves. Yah, that may be an ugly mess you've gotten into.

Comment: @zooter   Have you had any luck with this issue?

Comment: had the timing belt replaced at a shop once and the car was returned to me running rough, the mechanic said it was due to the ecu needing to adjust but actually they had replaced the spark plugs in the wrong order.  after swapping them to the correct order the car ran great, just something to check before jumping to the bent valves assumption.

Comment: @JohnDream on the 07 v6 it has coil on plug. If he had the crank pointing at 9 than it was almost 90* off from where it should be.

Comment: You shouldn't have blindly started the car before double and triple checking the alignment marks were lined up according to factory specs. It would also have been beneficial to take out the plugs and turn the crank with a wrench before using the starter. Your hand would probably have felt resistance when the valves and the pistons made contact, which would have been a relatively cheap diagnostic method compared to what you ended up doing. Redoing the belt would have taken time, but it would have been less time than replacing the heads and the belt.

Answer (score 6):

The OP indicated in their [comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21047/timing-belt-changed-wont-start#comment31171_21047) that they didn't maintain timing in the process of replacing the timing belt.

Since the 2007 Accord V6 has an [interference](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/23041/675) engine, attempting to crank the engine over with the timing off will result in mechanical damage, which would explain why it is running roughly.

Comment: I agree. Sorry, your isht is busted... Time for a rebuild or a different motor.

Answer (score 6):

quick tip if any one is doing their timing chain or belt. make sure you have a picture showing the tdc( top dead center), double check all the marks match exactly no error is tolerated here, the crank, exhaust cams, intake cams etc.

the tip is first throw the belt on the crank, then align the belt on the cam which ever is far away from the tensioner, then on the cam closer to the tensioner, mae sure you dont have any slack on the belt, have all the slack towards the tensioner this way you will reduce the chance of the belt jumping tooth.

after assembling the belt make sure there is no slack,rotate the crank it should rotate with out too much resitance and the belt should not be jumping.

Answer (score 6):

On the Honda SOHC V6 engine when doing timing the mark on the crank sprocket should line up with a small arrow on the block @ 12 o'clock.

The bank 2 cam gear should have the cylinder 1 TDC mark lining up with the indent on the backing plate.

The bank 1 cam gear is pretty much the same as bank 2. It has an indent and a mark on the cam gear.

A good practice to get into is rotating the crankshaft by hand after you have installed the tensioner and pulled the pin.

From the comments though it seems like your gonna need a new set of valves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after I did the timing belt on my sisters car (2000 honda accord v6) was also mentioned that after you replace the belt and add the tensioner like required.  Once all said and done with the install of belt, water pump gasket and pump, to rotate the motor by hand (with ratchet and socket) 3 or 6 full revolutions on the crank and all timing marks should align back up to all marks on the motor housing.  After i did all this, her car ran like a champ on the first time of doing the service.  now i make it a rule of thumb that if you do timing belt or chain, to rotate the motor 6 full revolutions (because cams rotate 1/2 speed of crank) and all timing marks will align back up properly.